# Why the principal value of complex number argument is taken within $(-\pi,\pi]?$

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question

Why the principal value of complex number argument is taken within $(-\pi,\pi]?$ What is the harm in considering similar other intervals like $[0,2\pi)$ for the purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutly no harm, it is just a convention. Usually one wants the argument function to be continuous around non negative reals.

Comment: @SugataAdhya If what you want to do is more to the left than to the right of the imaginary axis, then $[0, 2\pi)$ is better. It's all about context.

Comment: 'Usually one wants the argument function to be continuous around non negative reals.' Can you elaborate?