# Range of principal argument

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question

> For a polar representation of a complex number, why the principal argument is to be considered in $(-\pi, \pi]$ or how can it arise?

I read some books where they just maintained it, but they don't give any reason. Also I read in [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) where they maintain: *Some authors define the range of the principal value as being in the closed-open interval $[0, 2\pi)$*, but why? Further I search in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and get two same problems(links are [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415232/why-is-principle-value-of-argument-generally-taken-as-pi-pi), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307002/why-the-principal-value-of-complex-number-argument-is-taken-within-pi-pi)). But i am not satisfied with such comments only. I expect for a detailed explanation. **My special focus is how did it assumed.**  Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Those 'comments' are the answers. You need to explain why you are not satisfied.

Comment: @treeleaf can you briefly explain it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that makes it feel natural for me is that the value of the argument in $(-\pi,\pi)$ corresponds to **the shortest distance you have to walk**, from the origin at $1$, to reach a given point on the circle, where the sign tells you when the shortest path involves walking backwards.

The fact that you choose $\pi$ for the principal argument of $-1$, instead of $-\pi$, is a matter of choice.

Note: this is assuming walking along a unit circle, so that the angle actually corresponds to the arc-length.